# Матрица в C. Как это можно реализовать?

Tags: c, указатели, матрицы

Нужно применить ко всем элементам матрицы некоторую функцию, переданную по указателю.

Не очень понимаю, что за функция здесь имеется ввиду?

Comment: «что за функция» — просто какая угодно функция, на которую указывает переданный вам указатель

Comment: @andreymal можете пример привести?

Comment: `int matrix[N][M];  void f(int);` Задача - написать что-то типа `void g(int m[][M], void (*func)(int))`, в которой ко всем элементам матрицы применяется `func` - чтоб ее можно было вызвать как `g(matrix,f)`

Comment: @Harry спасибо попробую

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне все это видеться примерно так, если я конечно правильно понял вопрос

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void somedo1(void *_x)
{
    int *x = _x;
    *x = *x * *x;
}

void somedo2(void *_x)
{
    double *x = _x;
    *x = log(*x);
}

void func(void *matrix, size_t nmemb, size_t size, void (*f)(void *))
{
    char *m = matrix;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++)
        f(&m[i * size]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int    matrix1[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
    double matrix2[2][2] = {{1.2, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}};

    func(matrix1, 12, sizeof(*matrix1[0]), somedo1);
    func(matrix2,  4, sizeof(*matrix2[0]), somedo2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++, puts(""))
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%4d", matrix1[i][j]);

    puts("");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++, puts(""))
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            printf("%6.2lf", matrix2[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, вроде похоже на правду